# How do I change JAVASCRIPT_DEFAULT_SOURCES for my application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

When you call `javascript_include_tag :defaults` you usually get: `prototype.js`, `effects.js`, `dragdrop.js`, and `controls.js`.

These are stored in a constant in `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper` called 'JAVASCRIPT_DEFAULT_SOURCES`. My application uses jQuery, so I want to replace the Prototype references with something more useful.

I added an initializer with these lines, based on the source code from jRails:

```
ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper::JAVASCRIPT_DEFAULT_SOURCES = %w{ jquery-1.4.min jquery-ui jquery.cookie }
ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper::reset_javascript_include_default
```

But when I do this, I get: `warning: already initialized constant JAVASCRIPT_DEFAULT_SOURCES` during startup.

What's the correct way of changing this value? In the source code it checks for the constant before setting it, but apparently that happens before it runs the initializer scripts.

---

The Rails 3.0 release will provide much greater flexibility with choice of JS libraries, so I guess this is a problem with an expiration date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do something like this?

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.min", "jquery-ui", "jquery.cookie" %>
```

You dont need to use the ":defaults" option. Take at look at:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#M001713

Comment: Of course I'm already doing that. I'm trying to figure out how to use `:defaults` simply because I _want_ to. There's no reason why a web framework should be so tightly-coupled to a javascript framework.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/139471) on ruby-forum, you can't.  Although, if you look [here](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/10350), there are a few .diff files that you could grab that would at least let you do something like this:

```
# environment.rb
ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper::register_javascript_expansion :monkey, "head", "body", "tail"
ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper::register_stylesheet_expansion :monkey, "head", "body", "tail"

# your .erb/.haml files
javascript_include_tag :monkey
stylesheet_link_tag :monkey
```

I know this obviously doesn't help you do what you're trying to do, but hopefully it at least helps point you in a positive direction.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, although there was never a definite resolution to the question hence my asking it here. Hard-coding this stuff is such bad design I can't believe they don't provide an easy way to change it.

Comment: Agreed.  One of the first things I do in any new rails project is swap out all of the prototype stuff for jquery.